# json_decode : Getting value inside an array using PHP

Tags: php, json

I need to be able to read the number of apiaccountview_id inside the array of this response:

```
{
"errorCodes": null,
"result": {
    "apiaccountview_id": "553631",
    "apiaccountview_countryId": "UA",
    "apiaccountview_registrationIp": "531137938",
    "apiaccountview_phoneNumber": "12344512344"
},
"success": true
```

}

I am using

```
$obj = json_decode($response,true);
```

And I want to have this to show the **apiaccountview_id**

```
if ($obj['success'] =='true'){
  return array(
    'error' => 0,
      'msg' => "added successfully - " . $obj['result=>apiaccountview_id'] . ":" . $obj['result=>apiaccountview_id']
  );
}

else{
    return array(
      'error' => 1,
      'msg' => "Error in loading - " . $obj['errorCodes'] . ":" . $obj['result']
    );
    }
```

Since result is an array I was thinking on calling the value inside like this:

```
$obj['result=>apiaccountview_id']
```

But it didn't work.
Can you please help me understand why?
How can I get a value inside an json array?

Thank you,
Arye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `true` as second argument to `json_decode` which means that you will have associative array in your result. You can access `apiaccountview_id` like this:

`echo $obj['result']['apiaccountview_id'];`

If you want to return object instead of array, you should pass `false` (that's default value) and then you can access the property like this:

```
echo $obj->result->apiaccountview_id;
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked great. I have seen the answers on  "How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?"
"How can I access an array/object?"  and I could not put my finger on the exact way to read the value. I am sorry if it looks like I was asking the same question. Thank you.